# Can We Use TextIO After FileIO Java

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

I am Using DataFlow (Apache Beam) in Java. I have Multiple Files and each file can be very large. Currently i am using fileIo to read each Files which can read all files parallely, But i also want to read each lines of the file in parallel. Can we use TextIo After FileIO. If possible how can we achieve this, i have searched but did not found any solution. Any Help would be appreciated.

Currently i am using the below code to read Each File

`PCollection<FileIO.ReadableFile> inputFiles = pipeline.apply("Poll Input Files", FileIO.match().filepattern(fullPath)).apply(FileIO.readMatches());`

Comment: TextIO and FileIO are both source I/O transforms and can't be applied sequentially. If you could state what you pipeline is trying to achieve post reading files and lines, then we could help with this better.

Answer (score 3):

You can use fileIO `match` transforms followed by `TextIO.readFiles()` to read lines. See [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/d93c591deb21237ddb656583d74444ef7a4debba/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/TextIO.java#L111) for an example.